# Why $\|f-g\| \leq \sup_{h\in H}\frac{\|h\|}{\|Kh\|}\|K(f-g)\|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $f,g\in L^2$ with Lebesgue measure. and $K:L^2\to L^2$ be some linear and continuous operator. Show that
$$\|f-g\| \leq \sup_{h\in H}\frac{\|h\|}{\|Kh\|}\|K(f-g)\|$$
where $h\in H\subset L^2$.

Comment: Are there any assumptions on $K$? Is it linear, continuous?

Comment: Yes, linear and continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about 
$$
h=f-g?
$$
This will work even if $K$ is non linear.

Comment: @Lionville Pretty sure you mean $\|K(f-g)\| \le \ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality can be written as :

$$1 \leq \sup_{h\in H} \frac{\|h\|}{\|Kh\|}\frac{\|K(f-g)\|}{\|f-g\|}$$

But $$\frac{\|K(f-g)\|}{\|f-g\|} \leq \|K\|$$

And $$\frac{1}{\|K\|} = \inf_{h\in H} \frac{\|h\|}{\|Kh\|} \leq \sup_{h\in H} \frac{\|h\|}{\|Kh\|}$$

Hence

$$\sup_{h\in H} \frac{\|h\|}{\|Kh\|}\frac{\|K(f-g)\|}{\|f-g\|} \geq \sup_{h\in H} \frac{\|h\|}{\|Kh\|}\|K\| \geq \frac{\|K\|}{\|K\|}  \geq 1$$